# How to Round to the Nearest 0.5?

Tags: c#, .net

in my application
 Ex 1: Start time  12.30
   (-)End time    16.00   here i get the   value  as   3.7  but i  need  to  show  this  3.7 as  3.5 in my application
 Ex 2: Start time  12.00
   (-)End time    16.00   here i get the   value  as   4.0  here  there  is no need  to alter the value

(1.7,2.7,3.7,4.7,.... etc ) as  to be represented as(1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,.. etc )

so how  to    write an  function  for this  where  if the  vale  contains(1.7,2.7)  i  should  change to   1.5,2.5
  or if  it  contains  1.0,2.0  then there  is no  need  to replace any value?

Comment: 12.30, 16.00 etc represents Time of day?

Comment: It seemed to me that 12.00, 12.30 and 16.00 were meant to be times, in which case simple decimal subtraction was inappropriate. BUT if @prince23 is asking for a function that will effectively give differences in times TO THE NEAREST half hour, that's a slightly different problem. Not the way I would have approached the problem, but it may be according to the strict interpretation of the question.

Comment: What do you expect when the values are 1.15 or 1.45?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This extension method ought to do the job:

```
public decimal RoundToNearestHalf(this decimal value)
{
    return Math.Round(value * 2) / 2;
}

var num1 = (3.7).RoundToNearestHalf(); // 3.5
var num1 = (4.0).RoundToNearestHalf(); // 4.0
```

I've used the `decimal` type in the code because it seems you want to maintain base 10 precision. If you don't, then `float`/`double` would do just as well, of course.

Comment: Couldn't you also use Decimal.Round for this? i mean instead of Math.Round?

Answer (score 3):

Use the DateTime type.  Subtracting DateTime types returns a TimeSpan.  Use TimeSpan.TotalHours to get your result. E.g.:-

```
var x = DateTime.Parse("12:30");
var y = DateTime.Parse("16:00");

Console.WriteLine((y - x).TotalHours);
```

Comment: @Noldorin: The question is about finding the number of hours (including fractional parts) between two __times__.  I no longer agree that this answer is not addressing the question.

Comment: +1 that is the preferred solution in my opinion. The mentioned DateTime-class was designed for date/time maths and should be used.

Comment: Not really. price23 should be using TimeSpan from the start. Not DateTime nor any kind of number. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389198/if-condition-for-checking-the-value/1389345#1389345

Comment: @Alfred:  Thats a reasonable point but I don't agree.  The two values x and y represent 2 fixed points in time which are best expressed as DateTime whereas a TimeSpan represents a delta between two points in time.

Answer (score 3):

Use DateTime type to work with time. Example:

```
string time1 = "12:30";
string time2 = "16:00";
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Parse(time2)-DateTime.Parse(time2);
string diffString = diff.ToString("hh:mm"); // will be 03:30
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply hours with 60 and add minutes. You'll get total number of minutes.
12hours and 30 minutes = 720 + 30 = 750 minutes.
16 hours = 960 minutes.
Subtract the first value from the other and divide it by 60
(960 - 750) / 60 = 210 / 60 = 3.5

Answer (score 1):

You should use TimeSpan and round it off:

```
TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(12, 30, 0);
TimeSpan endTime = new TimeSpan(16, 0, 0);
TimeSpan span = endTime - startTime;
double totalHours = span.TotalHours;
double roundedToHalf = Math.Round(totalHours * 2) / 2;
Console.WriteLine(roundedToHalf);
```

---

UPDATE:

If the start and end time are from different dates, you should use DateTime for startTime and endTime.

Answer (score 0):

If the values in your question represent *times* you can't do decimal arithmetic with them and expect time values as results.

You need to manipulate the values as *times*

I don't know C#, but it must have some time functions.

Comment: .NET has a TimeSpan type that allows the minipulation of Delta Time.

Comment: One of these days, I'll find out exactly what people mean when they say '.NET' Who knows ... it may even be relevant in my day-to-day programming. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have the times as DateTime then use Timspan to find the difference between the two times?

Answer (score 0):

Times are not integers or floats.  You can't work with them as if they are - you wouldn't try to do integer math using the String class, would you?

DateTime and TimeSpan are you friends for this kind of data manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the C# Floor and Ceil method of the Math Class. Read more about it in the below URLs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling(VS.71).aspx
http://dotnetperls.com/math-floor

Answer (score -6):

```
string i = "2.0";
if (i == "2.3" || i == "3.3" || i == "4.3")
    {
        string strReplace = i.Replace(".3", ".5");

    }
    else 
    {
        string strReplace = i;
    }
```

Comment: What should happen if it is 2.15, 3.20 or 4.45?